# Not able to scrape image URLs using beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapinghub

So basically I am using the below code to scrape the image urls of the credit cards from the respective links in the explore_more_url variable.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, requests, re
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Hari\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")

img_url = []

explore_more_url = ['https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-ace-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-aura-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/privilege-easy-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/reserve-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-freecharge-plus-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/indianoil-axis-bank-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-magnus-card/feature-benefits', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/flipkart-axisbank-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-freecharge-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/my-zone-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/neo-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-vistara-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-vistara-signature-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-vistara-infinite-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/privilege-credit-card-with-unlimited-travel-benefits-account', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/miles-more-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-select-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/pride-platinum-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/pride-signature-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/my-zone-easy-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/insta-easy-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/signature-credit-card-with-lifestyle-benefits', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/platinum-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/titanium-smart-traveler-credit-card', 'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/my-wings-credit-card/features-benefits']

for x in explore_more_url:
    driver.get(x)
    soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    img_url.append("https://www.axisbank.com" + soup_1.find('img', alt="Fast Forward Banner").get('src'))

print(img_url)
```

**Output :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Hari\PycharmProjects\Card_Prj\axis.py", line 82, in <module>
   img_url.append("https://www.axisbank.com" + soup_1.find('img', alt="Fast Forward Banner").get('src'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The images are something like this in each link:
[image]

What is the appropriate code that I could use so that I can get exactly what I am expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting the image might be this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'
}
page = requests.get("https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-ace-credit-card", headers=headers).text
img_src_ = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").select_one('.bannerWrapper img')["src"]

with open(img_src_.rsplit("/")[-1], "wb") as image:
    image.write(requests.get(f"https://www.axisbank.com{img_src_}").content)
```

Output: an `.jpg` file in the script's local directory

```
ace-product-landing-web-version-1920x360.jpg
```

EDIT: To get just the source urls, try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'
}

explore_more_url = [
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-ace-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-aura-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/privilege-easy-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/reserve-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-freecharge-plus-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/indianoil-axis-bank-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-magnus-card/feature-benefits',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/flipkart-axisbank-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-freecharge-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/my-zone-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/neo-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-vistara-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-vistara-signature-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-vistara-infinite-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/privilege-credit-card-with-unlimited-travel-benefits-account',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/miles-more-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/axis-bank-select-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/pride-platinum-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/pride-signature-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/my-zone-easy-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/insta-easy-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/signature-credit-card-with-lifestyle-benefits',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/platinum-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/titanium-smart-traveler-credit-card',
    'https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card/my-wings-credit-card/features-benefits',
]

img_urls = []
for url in explore_more_url:
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    try:
        img_src_ = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").select_one('.bannerWrapper img')["src"]
        print(f"Finding image source url for {url}")
        img_urls.append(f"https://www.axisbank.com{img_src_}")
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        continue

print(img_urls)
```

Output:

```
['https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/ace-product-landing-web-version-1920x360.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/health-and-wellness-product-page-1920x360_v1.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/freecharge-product-landing-page-desktop-banner-revised.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/indian-oil-banner-desktop.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/img/magnuscard/apply-now.png', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/flipkart-abcc-desk.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/product-landing-page-desktop-banner.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/myzone-easy-1920-360-desktop-banner.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/neo-credit-card-1920-360-desktop-banner.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/vistara-1920-360-desktop-banner.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/vistara-1920-360-desktop-banner.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/vistara-1920-360-desktop-banner.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/privilege-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/miles---more-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/desktop-select-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/pride-platinum-1920-360-desktop-banner.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/pride-platinum-1920-360-desktop-banner.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/myzone-easy-1920-360-desktop-banner.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/insta-easy-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/signature-credit-card-with.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/platinum-credit-card.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/signature-credit-card-with.jpg', 'https://www.axisbank.com/images/default-source/revamp_new/cards/credit-cards/desktop/my-wings-credit-card.jpg']
```

Comment: @ baduker I highly appreciate the code you wrote, thanks for that, but at this point in time I simply need a list of all the image urls of the cards.

Comment: @ baduker words aren't enough to describe my gratitude to you, for your edit, but there is a small problem I have gone through the links in the output, some links give me the card image, and some links give not the card image, but some irrelevant image. I'd be glad if you could solve that.

Comment: @ baduker Yes, but there are some links which do not have banners but have card images somewhere down in the page.